# Running OpenCL code on intel CPU

Tags: opencl, intel

Now I'm testing running OpenCL source code on intel cpu.

I used the source code on this page (http://lava.cs.virginia.edu/Rodinia/download_links.htm)

I selected 2.4 version and certainly used NW-algorithm source code located in ../opencl/nw/ .

My environment is Windows 7 64bit OS / Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU W3530 / NVIDIA Quadro 600 .

I installed visual studio 2013 and NVIDIA 6.0 CUDA tookit .

At first, I could run this source on my gpu. And It operates very well.

But when I set use_gpu = 0 (this means CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU), program stoped at the first of opencl API function line. (maybe clGetPlatformIDs)

So I installed 64bit CPU only runtime on (https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk) and Intel SDK for OpenCL Applications 2014 Beta version on (https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk-beta).

But when I ran this file again, I got

```
'OpenCLProject2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCLProject2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Wldap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'OpenCLProject2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\cpu_device64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenCLProject2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\tbb\tbb.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x1438 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[4480] OpenCLProject2.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

this messages and clCreateContextFromType API returns error.

At this point I can't proceed my work.

I wonder why error lines include (Win32) or (x86) or System32 although I installed windows7 64bit OS and 64bit version of CPU only runtime.

Give me some advice. Thx.

Comment: "Cannot find or open the PDB file" means that dlls are loaded without debugging information (PDB). App error is not related to there messages.

Comment: ... and what the app error *is* related to is the return value of the failing OpenCL API call - so what exactly did `clCreateContextFromType ` return?

Comment: I used printf function to identify what is the error. Error code was -1 which means OpenCL devices were not found. I think still intel CPU is not recognized as a device.

Comment: Please try a tool like GPU Caps Viewer from Geeks3D.  It has an OpenCL tab that lists all available platforms and devices, allowing you to see if your CPU is listed.  I suspect that your specific Xeon CPU may not be supported by the OpenCL CPU runtime.  If that is the case then you might have more success with the AMD APP SDK's CPU runtime (works on many more CPUs from both Intel and AMD).

Comment: You might also want to check out [https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl#article-394094](this comparison) between Intel OpenCL SDK version as some only work on Xeon processors.